# Float to byte array conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, floating

We use

```
float f= 3.5f ;
BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
```

It returns byte array of length 4.  But I wonder the math behind this. Anyone will teach the math behind this conversion? Also double conversion info is appreciated.

Comment: there is no math or conversion, just a memory copy https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,f44ffc4f294cd463,references. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I was calling their thing as math. Thanks.

Comment: The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Single_) is a bit taciturn about the actual *semantics* of `GetBytes()`. That's probably because the authors thought it was self-understood that the return value is simply the bytes with which the argument value is represented or stored in memory. Float and double are "represented using the [...] IEEE 754 formats." (CSharp Language Specification 5.0, 1.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the covers, it is using unsafe, C-style pointers to copy the underlying 32-bit value into a 32-bit array (a `byte[4]`):

```
int rawBits = *(int*)&value;
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
fixed(byte* b = bytes)
    *((int*)b) = rawBits;
return bytes;
```

The results are architecture dependent, insofar as the order of the bytes matches the memory byte order (endianness) of the machine where the copy took place.

For example, if the 32-bit `rawBits` value is `0xAABBCCDD`, and it is represented in memory as `AA BB CC DD`, then the array will contain `0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD`.  If the in-memory representation was `DD CC BB AA`, then the array will contain `0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA`.